# Order By Month Name in Sql-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have Below Table named session

```
SessionID   SessionName

100         August
101         September
102         October
103         November
104         December
105         January
106         May
107         June
108         July
```

I executed the following query I got the output as below.

```
Select SessionID, SessionName 
From dbo.Session  

SessionID   SessionName
100         August
101         September
102         October
103         November
104         December
105         January
106         May
107         June
108         July
```

the results get ordered by Session ID. But I need the output as below,

```
SessionID   SessionName 
106         May
107         June
108         July
100         August
101         September
102         October
103         November
104         December
105         January
```

How to achieve this in sql-server? thanks for the help

Comment: Is there just the `SessionName` or is there some kind of date-value too?

Comment: there is value column created date. but it is also not in order

Comment: The problem is: Ho do you want to handle the year's end? January gets 13 and February gets 14? What if you have to sort more than 12 months?

Comment: it is a static table. irrespective of year it have 12 months only

Comment: This does **not** solve the problem... If there is a January you do not know wheter it has to be ordered in front or at the end...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a `case` expression, like:

```
order by case SessionName when 'August' then 1
                          when 'September' then 2
                          ...
                          when 'Juty' then 12
         end
```

August has 1 because "*in the application logic a session started with august*", easy to renumber if you want to start with January and end with December.

Comment: case statements looks long in the query. any other solution than this. for eg: is it possible to convert the monthname to month number and group according to it?

Comment: cte's or derived tables can be used. (Or perhaps a stored procedure/function.)

Comment: in the application logic a session started with august.

Comment: using case expression in order by gave syntax error

Comment: It did? Odd, that syntax has been in the ANSI SQL for ages. (At least since SQL-92.)

Comment: I get: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'August' to data type int.

Comment: @feijao, ask an own question. (Column data type int?)

Answer (score 3):

To avoid any hassel with culture dependencies, you might get the month's index out of sys languages with a query like this:

(I'd eventually create a TVF from this and pass in the `langid` as parameter)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) MyMonthIndex
        ,Mnth.value('.','varchar(100)') AS MyMonthName
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(months,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS XmlData
    FROM sys.syslanguages
    WHERE langid=0
) AS DataSource
CROSS APPLY DataSource.XmlData.nodes('/x') AS The(Mnth)
```

The result

```
1   January
2   February
3   March
4   April
5   May
6   June
7   July
8   August
9   September
10  October
11  November
12  December
```

#### EDIT: An UDF for direct usage (e.g. in an `order by`)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMonthIndexFromMonthName(@MonthName VARCHAR(100),@langId INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT MyMonthIndex
        FROM
        (
            SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS INT) MyMonthIndex
                  ,Mnth.value('.','varchar(100)') AS MyMonthName
            FROM
            (
                SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(months,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS XmlData
                FROM sys.syslanguages
                WHERE langid=@langId
            ) AS DataSource
            CROSS APPLY DataSource.XmlData.nodes('/x') AS The(Mnth)
        ) AS tbl
        WHERE MyMonthName=@MonthName
    );
END
GO

SELECT dbo.GetMonthIndexFromMonthName('February',0)
```

Comment: I like this, I wonder if it's possible to simplify CSV splitting little bit (or if CTE performs better?) but it's on the point

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, in most cases a CTE and an inlined sub-select leads to the same execution plan. There are tons of discussions on string splitting (SQL Server 2016 will bring this - sigh! - as a function!). With short string the XML approach is very fine, as long as you are sure, that there are no forbidden characters (like `<>&`) in the string parts...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM session 
ORDER BY MONTH(session.SessionName + ' 1 2014')
```

The part:

```
MONTH(session.SessionName + ' 1 2014')
```

Will return 3 of the month is march and you do not really need to care about the year in this case

Comment: NO! you really **never** should rely on culture depending formats! Try this: `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN; SELECT MONTH('January 1 2014')`

Answer (score 1):

Try `CAST` your Month Name (SessionName) into `DATETIME` format, just like this

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY DATEPART(mm, CAST(SessionName + '1900' AS DATETIME)) asc
```

Comment: NO! you really **never** should rely on culture depending formats! Try this: `SET LANGUAGE GERMAN; SELECT MONTH('January 2014')`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string month into number and sort by numer form month

```
SELECT SessionID, SessionName, DATEPART(MM, SessionName)
FROM dbo.Session
ORDER BY DATEPART(MM, SessionName)
```

otherwise, if you have something like "DateCreation" column, you can do something like this

```
SELECT SessionID, SessionName, MONTH(DateCreation)
FROM dbo.Session
ORDER BY MONTH(DateCreation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this .. I am assuming that you want next month of current Date is starting point so I am using "Month(GetDate()" in script otherwise you can hard-code to 4 to get desired result

```
Declare @Session Table (SessionID INT, SessionName Varchar(20))
Insert Into @Session Values (100,'August'),(101,'September'),(102,'October'),(103,'November'),(104,'December')
,(105,'January'),(106,'May'),(107,'June'),(108,'July')


Select * From @Session
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN Month(CAST('01-' + SessionName + ' 2016' AS DateTime)) - Month(GetDate()) <= 0 
                    THEN 12 + Month(CAST('01-' + SessionName + ' 2016' AS DateTime)) - Month(GetDate())
                    ELSE Month(CAST('01-' + SessionName + ' 2016' AS DateTime)) - Month(GetDate())  END
```

For GERMAN Language ..use below script .. In this i used soundex for month comparision

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN; 
Declare @Session Table (SessionID INT, SessionName Varchar(20))
Insert Into @Session Values (100,'August'),(101,'September'),(102,'October'),(103,'November'),(104,'December')
,(105,'January'),(106,'May'),(107,'June'),(108,'July')


Select * From @Session S
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT Number + 1 as [MonthNumber],
                DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm,Number,0)) as [MonthName]
                FROM master..spt_values
                WHERE Type = 'P' and Number < 12
        )M ON SoundEx(M.MonthName)=SoundEx(S.SessionName)   

        ORDER BY CASE WHEN [MonthNumber] - Month(GetDate()) <= 0 
                    THEN 12 + [MonthNumber] - Month(GetDate())
                    ELSE [MonthNumber] - Month(GetDate())  END
```

Comment: NO! you really **never** should rely on culture depending formats! Try this:`SET LANGUAGE GERMAN; SELECT CAST('01-' + 'January' + ' 2016' AS DateTime)`

Comment: Navee,  I see your edits :-) The problem with this might be, that at the moment you are depending on a `SET` command you must say good bye to any *ad-hoc SQL*, no inline function, no usage in a view...

Comment: And have a look here `select * from sys.syslanguages`. The soundex approach might work for similar languages, but is not reliable...